# div disappearing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

When reducing the browser window chrome, .sidebar (at some stage) will not be displayed.
In firefox all ok (. Sidebar does not disappear) and decreasing horizontal scrolling window appears. How to achieve the same for chrome?

.container should be stretchy. And gorizonalny scrolling should appear when .container < 550px

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    background: #CCC;
}

.container {
    float: left;
    max-width: 750px;
    min-width: 550px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar {
  float:left;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">In that case, Semak would be confronted with two of Zenit’s most difficult matches of the season. On Saturday, Zenit has a league class away to reigning Russian champions CSKA Moscow, before attempting to keep their European hopes alive away to Dortmund</div>
<div class="sidebar">In the meantime, the source said the team would be managed by reserves coach Sergei Semak</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because of the negative margin in sidebar class, try without margins in both .sidebar and .container and when the width in the window is less than the defined in the clases the last element will collapse.

Comment: WTF is _"gorizonalny scrolling"_?

Comment: @j08691 - Did you never type a word where you started your first finger on the wrong letter? it screws up the whole word :D I'm presuming he means 'horizontaly'

Answer (score 0):

Set the css of the body to:

position: absolute;